# Block are not displayed to anonymous users in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

Al my blocks in drupal are display only for the admin & not for the anonymous users who are not logged in.

Where i went wrong? I never faced this issue. did someone have solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for anonymous users and I am sure you can solve this problem.

There is setting for block visibility for each kind of user type.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install this module. Will be helpful to better manage of permissions. http://drupal.org/project/fpa

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the permissions section and also individual block permissions? Users can be denied access from any of these places. If all of that is set right, check your template to make sure there's not a hard coded PHP check (really bad form but I see it a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Also might help to check that your block placement on /admin/structure/block is set for the public facing theme and not just the admin theme.